# Getting specific excel(.xls) cell

Tags: vb.net

is there a way to get a specific cell in excel using this code ?.

```
 Try

        OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "Desktop"
        OpenFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Xls Files (*.xls)|*.xls"

        If OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
            Dim Filename As String = OpenFileDialog.FileName
            excel = fi.FullName
            conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
            dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", conn)
            dts = New DataSet
            dta.Fill(dts, "Sheet1$")
            DGV1.DataSource = dts
            DGV1.DataMember = "Sheet1$"
            conn.Close()

        End If
        lblRowCount.Text = DGV1.Rows.Count - 1
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        conn.Close()
        Exit Sub

    End Try
```

or is there a other way to import excel files to datagridview using loop inserting cell by cell ?.

Comment: Normally this code (retrieve excel information using ADO) is used to get a table-like content from Excel, which can be imported to a datatable. If you want to get an specific cell content would be better to use Excel.Application objects to get the information.

Comment: What is the problem with your current approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can print the C2 cell value with this code

```
'--------  Option Strict off ---------------
    Private Sub Button13_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
                Dim mypath As String
                Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
                Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
                Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
                mypath = "F:\Documents\myfile.xlsx"
                wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(mypath)
                ws = xlApp.Worksheets(1)
                MessageBox.Show(ws.cells(2, 3).value + " in cell C2")
                wb.Close()
                xlApp.Quit()
        End Sub
    ' --------- option strict on ------------------
    Private Sub Button13_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
        Dim percorso As String
        Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
        Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
        Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
        mypath = "F:\Documents\myfile.xlsx"
        wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(mypath)
        ws = CType(xlApp.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
        Dim xRng As Excel.Range = CType(ws.Cells(2, 3), Excel.Range)
        Dim val As Object = xRng.Value()
        MessageBox.Show(val.ToString + " in cell C2")
        wb.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()
    End Sub
```

Comment: I am having trouble with `ws.cells(2, 3).value`. As `ws.Cells(2,3)` returns an `Object` it has no `.Value` property. It needs to be cast to the underlying datatype. Try your code with Option Strict on.

Comment: You are right Mary, I tested with Option Strict Off

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.